# Select ID for each max column in a single mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table ###  **inf_simpleranks**

```
+-----+--------------+----------+---------+----------+
| uid | style_normal | style_sw | style_w | style_ad |
+-----+--------------+----------+---------+----------+
|   1 |          159 |        9 |     164 |      195 |
|   2 |           46 |       39 |      55 |      159 |
|   3 |          188 |       28 |     171 |      174 |
|   4 |          135 |       32 |     151 |       63 |
|   5 |            3 |      156 |     173 |      197 |
+-----+--------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I can get the max value for each column

```
select 
  a.uid,
  a.style_normal
from
  inf_simpleranks a
  inner join (
    select max(style_normal) as style_normal
    from inf_simpleranks
  ) b on a.style_normal = b.style_normal;


+-----+--------------+
| uid | style_normal |
+-----+--------------+
|   3 |          188 |
+-----+--------------+
```

And this

```
+-----+----------+
| uid | style_sw |
+-----+----------+
|   5 |      156 |
+-----+----------+
```

Sometimes the UID would match

```
+-----+----------+
| uid | style_ad |
+-----+----------+
|   5 |      197 |
+-----+----------+
```

But I am trying to get it into a single query so it would look like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| MAX            | UID          |
+----------------+--------------+
| style_normal   | 3            |
| style_sw       | 5            |
| style_w        | 5            |
| style_ad       | 5            |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `union all` might be the best approach:

```
(select 'style_normal' as which, style_normal, uid
 from inf_simpleranks
 order by style_normal desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select 'style_sw' as which, style_sw, uid
 from inf_simpleranks
 order by style_sw desc
 limit 1
) union all
. . .
```

If your data is not too big (due to internal constraints on `group_concat()` and you can have the values in columns, you can do:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(uid order by style_normal desc), ',', 1) as style_normal,
       substring_index(group_concat(uid order by style_sw desc), ',', 1) as style_sw,
       . . .
from inf_simpleranks;
```

Comment: `which` should be `MAX` and I think you mean `as uid` not `, uid` (otherwise I was writing the same query)

Comment: Brilliant, that's so smart to do the limit 1 using DESC!  Worked perfectly!  Thank you!!!  I had to remove the second column though  (select 'style_normal' as MAX_COL, uid from inf_simpleranks order by style_normal desc limit 1) union all
(select 'style_sw' as MAX_COL, uid from inf_simpleranks order by style_sw desc limit 1) union all
(select 'style_w' as MAX_COL, uid from inf_simpleranks order by style_w desc limit 1) union all
(select 'style_ad' as MAX_COL, uid from inf_simpleranks order by style_ad desc limit 1)